# Freemarker regex is not matching on all lowercase substrings

Tags: java, regex, freemarker

So I am following the user guide, which seems straight forward so I'm not sure what it is I am doing wrong. I want to use the `matches` builtin to find all lower case words in a string. So, taking the example straight from the docs, into my code (with some obvious changes), I always get the `Does not match` output. Any help is much appreciated:

```
<#assign res = "<UPPERCASE_WORD<lowercase_word>>"?matches("[a-z]+")>
  <#if res>
     Matches
  <#else>
     Does not match
  </#if>
```

One thing that I've noticed between my code and the docs is that the example has spaces and I do not, but I doubt that's the issue as a quick test with `< >` replaced with spaces shows no difference. I was thinking the regex is incorrect or not supported by Freemarker, but the docs link directly to [OracleRegexPattern docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) so I think that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [matches](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_matches) if you don't expect an **exact** match:

> This built-in determines if the string **exactly** matches the pattern

If you know the appropriate exact regex use it,

For example for lower letters and then upper cases letters use:

```
?matches("[a-z]+[A-Z]+")>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the string contains `[a-z]` *somewhere*, then the regular expression should be `".*[a-z]+.*"`, because `?matches` checks if the pattern matches the *whole* string.